# Pass session parameters from php to ruby

Tags: php, ruby, wordpress, forms

I have a WordPress website. I now use Ruby to build web apps. I am trying to get form data from the wordpress site into my ruby app which is hosted on a subdomain of the same website.

e.g. html form is at mydomain.com (wordpress site written in php)
ruby app hosted at subdomain.mydomain.com (written in ruby)

The ruby app needs to receive the form input data (as securely as possible).

Current form code:

```
<form action="/inbox" method="POST">
```

The current form action simply directs the parameters to a ruby route. Is this enough to have ruby pick up the parameters?

Comment: Yes, provided your ruby app is being hit by the `POST` it will have all the form data available to your app in `params`

Answer (score 0):

Pass your extra need parameter in the header of the request.